# Google Maps API - Geometry Encoding - TypeError: a.lat is not a function

Tags: encoding, google-maps-api-3, typeerror, geopoints

I have a list of GeoPoints in an array with looks like this:

```
var coordinates = [[50.7, 6.7], [49.5, 7.0], ...]
```

When I try to use `encodePath` for minifying the code as [explained here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding), I get the following error:

> TypeError: a.lat is not a function

My code looks like this:

```
google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(coordinates)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I found the solution! The problem was that `encodePath` expects a `google.maps.LatLng` object and not just the `GeoPoints`.

Here is a function which turns an array like the one descripted above into an encoded string:

```
function encodeLatLngPolygon(array) {

var polyOptions = {
strokeColor: '#000000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 3
  }
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);

var path = poly.getPath();

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    var xyz = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(array[i][0]).toFixed(2), parseFloat(array[i][1]).toFixed(2));
    path.push(xyz);            

}

var code = google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath(path)

return code;
}
```

The `toFixed` reduces the numbers after the decimal point for saving bytes. You can delete or adjust this parameter.